# Boradcast join is too slow in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have 2 table like this:

Table A: ind , value1

**(1,a)(2,b)(3,c)** ... 3 billion rows

Table B: start_ind,end_ind,value2

**(3,20,c)(78,99,y)(88,156,z)** ... 500 million rows

And i write this query in spark sql

```
Select /*+ BROADCAST(B) */ A.ind,A.value1,B.value2
From A join B on A.ind between B.start_ind and B.end_ind;
```

I give 5 executor cores , 700 num of executor, 50gb memory to executor .

The query never ends

How can i improve the performance

Comment: How is your `B` dataset sorted?

Comment: B is not sorted but A is sorted

Comment: Have you tried it without broadcast?

Comment: Yep same it is too slow